# ESLint rule for unused imports, is it possible to ignore few imports out of many?

Tags: ignore, unused-variables, unused-functions

i am using un-used imports rule to list all un-used imports from all files.
but we have few imports which are un-used but those should stay.

so wondering, is it possible ignore few un-used imports?

this is the rule i am using:

```
rules: {
        "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
        "no-unused-vars": "off",
      },
```